# Putty on windows - save aliases

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, alias

I want to use aliases when I connect to ssh via Putty (on Windows). But the aliases get deleted when I close the session.

Is there any way to keep these aliases?

I tried to add them to connection -> ssh -> remote command, for example:

```
alias a="cd .."; bash
```

but it does not work, when I connect, the alias is simply not there.

Other commands seem to be working (like the mentioned cd .., ls, ...) but for some reason alias does not.

Is it possible to save aliases/have them loaded on session start?

Comment: The big misunderstanding here is the problem has anything to do with PuTTY. No. PuTTY is a terminal emulator and SSH client. Aliases belong to a shell. [This is how you define permanent aliases for Bash](https://askubuntu.com/a/17537/693277), other shells may have their specific solutions. Believing aliases have something to do with PuTTY is like expecting your desktop icons to disappear after you change your physical (hardware) monitor to another model. PuTTY will be relevant only if you want to have different aliases when you connect with PuTTY than otherwise. Is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you first specify the alias command and then start bash. The other way around would be better: first start bash and then define the alias:

```
bash --init-file <(echo "alias a='cd ..'")
```

Using this as `remote command` for an SSH connection the alias can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the aliases to the user on the *host machine*, PuTTY just opens a session (which disappears again when you close it, assuming you're not using *screen* of course).

Use vi, mcedit or any other editor to edit .bash_aliases in your remote user's home directory:

```
vi ~/.bash_aliases
```

I've browsed around briefly, and this page looks pretty descriptive of how to use it: https://opensource.com/article/19/7/bash-aliases

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate that it's not exactly what you want to do, but this might help some other people looking how to achieve similar.

```
doskey ssh="C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe"
doskey ssh-agent="C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pageant.exe"
doskey ssh-keygen="C:\Program Files\PuTTY\puttygen.exe"
```

I haven't quite got it to pass command line arguments (yet) but it's a starting point.